# VS Code Mac OSX with TFS

Tags: macos, azure-devops, visual-studio-code

I have installed VS Code to Mac OSX. I would like to connect to my companies TFS server , so I could work on the project from mac as well .

The company is not using Visual Studio Team Services (was VS Online), still using TFS on company servers.

I see that there are ways to connect to Team Services with git settings, but how can I cannot to TFS from Mac VS Code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Code currently only supports Git, so your company's TFS must be hosting a Git Repostory for that to work. You can access TFVC using Team Explorer Everywhere and/or the cross platform commandline tools. If you want something close to integration with VS Code, consider git-tf(s), which will create a local git repository which you can push to TFS.